# Injecting values from a child template into a parent template in Jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

I have created a Jinja2 template called lesson.html that defines the basic structure of a lesson. From that, I derive one child template for each actual lesson (since the content of each lesson is different).  For example, intro.html, variables.html, lists.html, and functions.html all derive from lesson.html.

Along with slides, exercises, and what-not, each actual lesson has a YouTube video.  I want to put the ID of the video in the child template file, but then put the HTML that actually references videos in the parent template (i.e., lesson.html) to ensure that every video is referenced and formatted the same way.  For example, I would like lesson.html to look like:

```
<div class="youtube"><br/>
    <iframe title="{{TITLE}}" time="{{TIME}}" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/{{ID}}"></iframe>
<br/>
</div>
```

and then have TITLE, TIME, and ID all defined in the child template file itself (since that's the most logical place to store them).  My current hack is to create a function that takes these values as arguments and returns a blob of HTML to be inserted in the right place:

```
{{youtube("Title of this Lecture", "abcde01234", "05:10")|safe}}
```

but (a) I'd rather use straight template expansion than function calls, and (b) the title, YouTube ID, and time aren't explicitly identified in the lesson template file (which makes them harder to extract for use elsewhere: I can do it with regular expressions, but I'd really rather not).

Is there a clean way to define values in a child template for use in a parent template?

Comment: I assume you use template inheritance. What do you mean with "define values in the child template"? You can pass these variables in the context of the child.

Comment: what was the solution you came up with greg? I would like to know if there is a possible way to do this.

Comment: Never found an answer...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass variables from child template to parent in Jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833370/pass-variables-from-child-template-to-parent-in-jinja2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [set](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#assignments), DOC are as follows:

> Inside code blocks, you can also assign values to variables. Assignments at top level (outside of blocks, macros or loops) are exported from the template like top level macros and can be imported by other templates.

Same question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833370/pass-variables-from-child-template-to-parent-in-jinja2?rq=1).