# Pass variables from child template to parent in Jinja2

Tags: jinja2

I want to have one parent template and many children templates with their own variables that they pass to the parent, like so:

parent.html:

```
{% block variables %}
{% endblock %}

{% if bool_var %}
    {{ option_a }}
{% else %}
    {{ option_b }}
{% endif %}
```

child.html:

```
{% extends "parent.html" %}

{% block variables %}
    {% set bool_var = True %}
    {% set option_a = 'Text specific to this child template' %}
    {% set option_b = 'More text specific to this child template' %}
{% endblock %}
```

But the variables end up undefined in the parent.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Ah. Apparently they won't be defined when they are passed through blocks. The solution is to just remove the block tags and set it up like so:

parent.html:

```
{% if bool_var %}
    {{ option_a }}
{% else %}
    {{ option_b }}
{% endif %}
```

child.html:

```
{% extends "parent.html" %}

{% set bool_var = True %}
{% set option_a = 'Text specific to this child template' %}
{% set option_b = 'More text specific to this child template' %}
```

Comment: My `parent.html` doesn't directly use my `bool_var` but rather has an `include` statement which includes another template which does use `bool_var`. In this included template the variable was coming out undefined until in the `parent.html` file I either used the variable such as `{{ bool_var }}` or did the tautological `{% set bool_var = bool_var %}`.

Comment: This is not working for me. The values are not being propagated to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

If Nathron's solution does not fix your problem, you can use a function in combination with a global python variable to pass a variable value.

- Advantage: The variable's value will available in all templates. You can set the variable inside a block.
- Disadvantage: More overhead.

This is what I did:

child.j2:

```
{{ set_my_var('new var value') }}
```

base.j2

```
{% set my_var = get_my_var() %}
```

python code

```
my_var = ''


def set_my_var(value):
    global my_var 
    my_var = value
    return '' # a function returning nothing will print a "none"


def get_my_var():
    global my_var 
    return my_var 

# make functions available inside jinja2
config = { 'set_my_var': set_my_var,
           'get_my_var': get_my_var,
           ...
         }

template = env.get_template('base.j2')

generated_code = template.render(config)
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, you can avoid this 'parameter-passing' by creating another variant of the parent that adds/removes some block and extends it instead.

```
{% extends [condition]|yesno:'parent_1.html,parent_2.html' %}
```