# Jinja: How to override variables in super block?

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

I've got a template `parent.tpl`:

```
{% set myvar = 'AAA' %}

{% block par %}
{{ myvar }}
{% endblock %}
```

and a `child.tpl`

```
{% extends "parent.tpl" %}

{% block par %}
{% set myvar = 'BBB' %}
{{ super() }}
{% endblock %}
```

the `child.tpl` results:

```
AAA
```

but not

```
BBB
```

How can I get `BBB` output with variable override?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Flask, you can use a global variable like `g.myvar`. It will be available in every template.

Take a look at [Pass variables from child template to parent in Jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24836460/974317).